# iTunes will not reinstall

Tags: itunes, windows, install

My (Win10) iTunes stopped working, so I uninstalled it (with a good uninstaller that clears all the debris), but it will not re-install.
For iTunes Desktop the error message is "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2503."
For iTunes from the Microsoft Store the error message is "The system could not find the environment option that was entered."
Any ideas on a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the installer from Apple (https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes) and right-clicking the downloaded file and selecting Run as Administrator? I've found that 2503 is sometimes due to permission issues

Comment: Google says "could not find the environment option" is an issue with your system variables/paths. idk whether this would be quicker to fix manually or by re-installing Windows using the 'preserve apps/settings' option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here’s what worked:

1. Delete the contents of *all* temp folders.
2. Using a good uninstaller that clears leftover debris, uninstall all Apple applications.
3. In the registry, under the software categories, delete anything to do with Apple.

That solved it. iTunes from the Microsoft Store installed without any problems. Interestingly, the installer downloaded from Apple still did not install.

I don't know if all the above steps are necessary, or whether just one or two did the trick.